# Update java.util.prefs.preferences from shell script or terminal

Tags: java, shell, terminal, preferences

I have saved few of my data in my machine through java preference. Under this node data are stored at the time of system loading and this works perfect for me.

Preferences registry = Preferences.userRoot().node("com/ABC/test");

Now, my clients want to update this Preferences entry through shell or terminal at run time. Through java it's easy but how can I update this through shell or terminal?

Answer (score 0):

-Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=/com/ABC/test

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).